# C++ Expected class member or base class name

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

/**
 * @struct matrix_dims
 * @brief Matrix dimensions container. Used in MlpNetwork.h and main.cpp
 */
typedef struct matrix_dims
{
    int rows, cols;
} matrix_dims;

class Matrix
{
 public:
  // constructors and destructors
  Matrix();
  Matrix(int rows, int cols);
  Matrix(const Matrix& m); // copy-ctr
  ~Matrix();

 private:
  int _rows;
  int _cols;
  float *_mat;
};

#endif //MATRIX_H
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>

Matrix::Matrix (): _rows(1), _cols(1), _mat(new float[1]())
{
}

Matrix::Matrix (int rows, int cols)
{
  if (rows <= 0 || cols <= 0)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("Invalid sizes for matrix");
    }
  _rows = rows;
  _cols = cols;
  _mat = new float[rows * cols]();
}

Matrix::Matrix (const Matrix &m):
{
  _rows = m._rows;
  _cols = m._cols;
  _mat = new float[_rows * _cols]();
  for (int i = 0; i < m._rows; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < m._cols; j++)
        {
          _mat[i * _cols + j] = m._mat[i * _cols + j];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix ()
{
  delete[] _mat;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
#include "Activation.h"
#include "Dense.h"
#include "MlpNetwork.h"
```

Dense.h

```
#ifndef DENSE_H
#define DENSE_H

#include "Activation.h"

// Insert Dense class here...


#endif //DENSE_H
```

Activation.h

```
#include "Matrix.h"

#ifndef ACTIVATION_H
#define ACTIVATION_H

// Insert Activation class here...

#endif //ACTIVATION_H
```

MlpNetwork.h

```
#ifndef MLPNETWORK_H
#define MLPNETWORK_H

#include "Dense.h"

#endif // MLPNETWORK_H
```

however, in the implementation of the copy constructor of Matrix, I get an error by the compiler: "Expected class member or base class name".
I can't see what's the problem. I guess there is a cycle dependency but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Off-topic: Negative values are meaningless anyway – you could express that fact by using `unsigned int` instead of `signed int` (well, correct type for specifying array sizes actually is `size_t`!), and as a bonus this test `if (rows <= 0 || cols <= 0)` would get entirely obsolete...

Comment: About the includes, in `Activation.h`, you should put the `#include ...` *after* the `#ifndef ... #define ...`. It's not likely to fix the compilation error, but just in case...

Comment: please include the complete error message in the question

Comment: Within the copy constructor you don't need the double loop, a single one is totally fine if you iterate from 0 to the product of rows and cols; much nicer, though, is the standard library: `_mat = new float[...]; std::copy(m._mat, m._mat + rows*cols, _mat);`

Comment: You can profit from constructor delegation for your default constructor: `Matrix() : Matrix(1, 1) { }` to avoid code duplication. Alternatively you could provide default arguments, though this would allow to specify just the rows and cols still defaulting to 1 – if you insist on both or none then you need the two constructors.

Comment: Recommend preferring `new float[...];` (note: no parentheses) within the *copy* constructor, you are going to overwrite the array anyway, so no need to zero-initialise...

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra colon at the end of line `Matrix::Matrix (const Matrix &m):`. After the colon the compiler expects a class member (for example `_rows`) or a base class name, for example a call to another constructor.